# WELD-001456: Argument bean must not be null

Tags: wildfly, cdi, myfaces, weld, jsf-2.3

I have an EAR File that contains two WARs. In WAR1 there is a JSF application (everything worked fine with JSF2.2 and ManagedBeans). After migrating to JSF2.3 with CDI beans I'm getting the following Exception when trying to access the web applicaton:

> WELD-001456: Argument bean must not be null
> (complete stack trace below)

Here my EAR's structure

```
EAR   
  |- WAR1
      |-WEB-INF\beans.xml
      |-WEB-INF\lib\myfaces-api-2.3.7.jar
      |-WEB-INF\lib\myfaces-impl-2.3.7.jar   
  |- WAR2
      |-WEB-INF\beans.xml
```

If I deploy the EAR with just WAR1 it works. I googled but could not find an answer.
I'm using Wildfly 19.1.0. The same exception happened also just after the upgrade to myfaces2.3.7 (without the migration to CDI).

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument bean must not be null
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:87)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.cdi.util.CDIUtils.resolveInstance(CDIUtils.java:65)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.cdi.util.CDIUtils.lookup(CDIUtils.java:52)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.ResolverBuilderBase.isReplaceImplicitObjectResolverWithCDIResolver(ResolverBuilderBase.java:232)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.ResolverBuilderForFaces.build(ResolverBuilderForFaces.java:108)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createFacesResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:408)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:389)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:230)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.getELContext(FacesContextWrapper.java:85)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._handleResourceDependency(ApplicationImpl.java:2551)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._handleResourceDependencyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:2515)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._handleAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:2285)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1537)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:141)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2549)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createCompiler(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2188)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2487)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:308)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:129)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:78)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:185)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:148)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.checkResourceExists(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:591)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.handleSuffixMapping(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:521)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.calculateViewId(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:86)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerImpl.java:124)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:127)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:222)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:195)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:142)
at deployment.myapp.ear.web.war//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:204)
... 72 more
```

Comment: It seams to be a bug on myfaces CDIUtils.java#L65. The bean manager does not resolve the desired bean. I can't help any further without knowing which bean is not being injected or how your beans are (or not) annotated). Can you add the CDI beans affected?

Comment: BeanManager: Weld BeanManager for myapp.ear [bean count=31].
beans is an empty collection;
I cannot see which bean(s) is causing the issue

Comment: Can you post a small project that reproduces the issue, or show the concrete code? It would be valuable to know how you are injecting your beans. Also, myfaces published a new stable version (2.3.8). Please update your libs and report if the bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Each ear and war in jboss has its own bean manager. The static method CDI.current().getBeanManager() used by myfaces can return the wrong one.
I solved a similar issue with this additional configuration in ServletContextListener:

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("org.apache.myfaces.annotation.USE_CDI_FOR_ANNOTATION_SCANNING", "true");
servletContext.setAttribute("javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager", (new InitialContext()).lookup("java:comp/BeanManager"));
```